# ArgumentError: Error #2109: Frame label play not found in scene Scene 1

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

I'm trying to get a movie clip to play when clicked.

```
square.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playME);

function playME(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndPlay("play");
}
```

that is the code i'm using in my scene, and I have a play label in the movie clip.

I don't know how to link the action in the scene to the label in the movie clip?

I did it somehow but undid alot of the work and now I can't remember how to do it..

Answer (score 1):

If the `square` is the `MovieClip` you want to play, use `square.gotoAndPlay("play");`